# Using EngineYard, when I do 'ey deploy' where in the filesystem is the application pushed?

Tags: engineyard

Using EngineYard, I push my code using 'ey deploy'.

When I then log into the linux box with ssh, where can I expect to find my project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pushed to:

```
/data/yourappname/current
```

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy, the server-side script checks out the code to

`/data/APPNAME/shared/cached-copy`

https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard-serverside/blob/master/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb#L17

Next, it is rsynced to all instances in `/data/APPNAME/releases` and the deploy hooks are run

https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard-serverside/blob/master/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb#L28

If all the deploy hooks succeed, we symlink the release directory to `/data/APPNAME/current`

You can find the running code in current, the last three deploys in releases and if you had a failed deploy, it gets moved to `/data/APPNAME/releases_failed`

More details on the Git code can be found in

https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard-serverside/blob/master/lib/engineyard-serverside/source/git.rb